# Uwamp support for php:7.0.4

Tags: uwamp

When checked in the Uwamp website, I am not able to see PHP version related information associated with each Uwamp version. Can I know if any of the Uwamp versions supports: PHP 7.0.2/PHP 7.0.6/PHP 7.0.6? If if is not, when the support for this versions expected? Please help.

Answer (score 1):

UwAmp already supports all the latest PHP versions. There is an option within the software to download and install the latest version (via the puzzle icon in the main window).

For some reason though it seems to have stopped working after PHP7.2.3. But it`s very easy to install versions manually. I have just installed PHP7.2.4, PHP7.1.16 & PHP7.0.29. Hopefully the auto installer starts working again soon.

Comment: If the auto update doesn`t work, download the PHP versions from PHP.net and add them to the 'bin/php' folder, maintaining the correct naming convention. Then start the UwAmp control panel, it will auto detect the new versions and install them.